# get data from mysql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc

How get data from mysql database? I use ASP.NET and C#.Previously, I used LINQ but it does not work with mysql database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [MySQL ADO.NET provider](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/). Download it, and try learning by looking at the examples. They're pretty straightforward.

Comment: where can I found these examples

Comment: Download the ADO.NET provider for MySQL. It comes with a couple of examples.

Answer (score 2):

There are several LINQ providers for MySQL, such as [DbLinq](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/) (FOSS) and [LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/blog/index.php/2008/06/08/introducing-linq-to-lightspeed/) (commercial).

Comment: whether the DbLinq can make dbml file of tables from server explorer

Comment: There is a tool like sqlmetal for DbLinq. Off the top of my head, I don't know whether it has the same name or a different one.